# Windows 7 disconnects and reconnects to WIFI every couple of minutes

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

This does not occur on the Ubuntu partition of the same computer, as well as on other Mac/Linux computers. I have seen a few questions here asking about similar issues, but those seem to be when the computer can't connect at all or is flapping - for me it is more intermittent. What steps should I take to debug/fix this?

Comment: Start of with drivers (check the power options on the NIC too). Then move onto DHCP (are you needing to get a new lease due to a conflict?). Firewall and AV inspection causing you issues? Does the same error occur in Safe Mode with Networking?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove your all your Firewalls (Windows and antivirus)?
If it works you have a Software that do the cut on purppose...

Otherwise it could be a Problem with your Network Driver you need to update compatible for your OS.